# WPF frozen BitmapImage not showing

Tags: wpf, bitmapsource, freezable

I am using a viewmodel bound to an image property on the UI and the viewmodel contains an ImageSource property. I set that property using the following function

```
    private BitmapImage GetImageFromUri(Uri urisource)
    {
        if (urisource == null)
            return null;

        var image = new BitmapImage();
        image.BeginInit();
        image.UriSource = urisource;
        image.EndInit();
        image.Freeze(); //commenting this shows the image if the routine is called from the proper thread.

        return image;
   }
```

For some odd reason, in the following code, when I call Freeze on my BitmapImage, it does not appear on the main window.I get no exception or crash. Can anybody help me with this?
I am setting the image property asynchronously so I need to be able to use the created image, assuming the GetImageFromUri call was made from a thread other than the UI thread.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the CacheOption for BitmapImage before freezing it. See if this works -

```
var image = new BitmapImage();
image.BeginInit();
image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
image.UriSource = urisource;
image.EndInit();
image.Freeze();
```

Answer (score 1):

Before you freeze it, you need to fully render it.
You should try to listen to the SourceUpdated event, and only then freeze the image.

On a side note, if you ever want to modify the Image after that, you will have to Clone it.

Comment: What do you mean by render it?

Comment: Graphically rendered. Settings the source does not make it visualizable, WPF first needs to render the image. It looks like you're freezing it before WPF gets the chance to do it.

Answer (score 0):

IF i use `StreamSource`, for me is enough:

```
public static BitmapSource ToBitmap(this MemoryStream stream)
    {
        try
        {
            using (stream)
            {
                stream.Position = 0;
                var image = new BitmapImage();
                image.BeginInit();
                image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                image.StreamSource = stream;
                image.EndInit();
                image.Freeze();
                return image;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

But if i use `UriSource` i need:

```
public static async Task<BitmapSource> ToBitmapAsync(this string sourceUri)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            using (var stream = await client.OpenReadTaskAsync(new Uri(sourceUri)))
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                stream.CopyTo(ms);
                return ms.ToBitmap();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

`BitmapSource` has `UriSource`, but it works after xaml rendered